# What is video hinting?

Tags: encoding

I've just faced with such thing as hinting videos. Quick research showed me something about the fact that it makes "streaming better" and something about QuickTime Streaming Server. That wasn't really clear or accurate in any way. So, I have a bunch of questions.

What exactly video hinting does? What do hinting tacks contain? And how they make streaming better?